# How to connect my mobile app to a database: SQL Server does not exist or access is denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I am trying to connect my app, developed in C#, with a SQL Server database.

The program is done! It's a **mobile app**.

My database is on `C:\ProgramFiles\MyAppName\MyDatabase.sdf`

My code line is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server =" + iP.Text  +"," + port.Text + ";integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=" + DB.Text + ";User ID=" + userName.Text + ";Password=" + Pass.Text + ";Trusted_Connection=False;");

iP.Text = my IP (102.168.XXX.XXX)
port.Text = 49214 or 1433
DB.Text = "MyDatabase.sdf"
userName.Text= "sa"
pass.Text= "MyPass"
```

But when I try to connect it, the app says:

> er.Message = "El servidor SQL Server no existe o se ha denegado el acceso.

My server name is the same as my userName?

The application was made by someone else; I did nothing. But now I have to change some things and make it better. There is no manual.

Any idea? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Check this out.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966559/how-i-create-a-sql-server-compact-3-5-sdf-file-and-connect-to-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Sql Server Compact Edition` (SDF file)  not `Sql Server`.
The classes needed to connect to this kind of database are different

```
  SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(......)
```

The classes for Sql Server cannot parse correctly your connection string and you get the mentioned error. Of course, the classes for Sql Compact Edition require a reference to the appropriate DLL

```
 System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

and the appropriate using statement at the beginning of your code file

```
 using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

As last note, the connection string for a SQL CE database is simply

```
 "Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf; Password ='<pwd>'"
```

doesn't seem possible to pass a specific user. See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/)

Comment: I never have to deal with that edition.  I assume this is for hand held devices?

Comment: No, it could be used also in desktop and web applications. See [Microsoft Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172448.aspx)

Comment: Ummmhh @Steve Could you help me: I have: 

`SqlConnection conn0 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Mydatabase.sdf;Password=MyPass;Persist Security Info=True");                                                                                 

if (conn0.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
 conn0.Open();`               

but It shows me the message: 

`er.Message = "No se encuentra el servidor SQL Server especificado: \\Archivos de programa\\Active_AFMobile\\ACTIVEAFMOB.sdf"` What could I do?

Comment: **SqlCeConnection** not SqlConnection. Notice the Ce part?

Comment: I used **SqlCeConnection** but in my next line code: `SqlCommand sqlS = new SqlCommand("Select * from USERS WHERE TRSM = '" + lbl2.Text + "'", conn0);` says: `Error 2 Argumento '2': no se puede convertir de 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection' a 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` I'm so sorry guy. I'm a green!

Comment: It is not just the connection. Every class that you use should be from the SqlServerCe namespace. **SqlCeCommand**, **SqlCeDataAdapter**, **SqlCeDataReader**

Comment: Also I am not sure that your syntax to find the path part of the SDF file is correct. I would use `Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(‌​).Location) + "\\Mydatabase.sdf`

Comment: #OMFG @Steve it works! it really works! thank you so much! U are the best!

Comment: As last tip, remember that in newest OS, placing a database file in the Program Files folder leads to problems because this folder is no more open to read/write ops like before. Read about Environment.SpecialFolder enum

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43632/discussion-between-jean-and-steve)